# What's the equivalent of CloseableService in Quarkus / RestEasy

Tags: quarkus, resteasy

I am migrating a REST-Service from Jersey to Quarkus/RestEasy. Jersey can inject different Context objects into the Resource classes, among them is a [CloseableService](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/server/CloseableService.html) that you can use to robustly handle Closeable resources, no matter what goes wrong with the request (Runtime Exceptions, Aborted Connections, etc.).

The signature of a resource method looks roughly like this:

```java
    @Path("/datasets/{dataset}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @GET
    public Stream<TSRecord> getDatasetDataJson(
            @PathParam("dataset") final String dsName,
            @QueryParam("parameter") final Parameter parameter,
            @Context final CloseableService closer
    ) throws NoSuchDatasetException {
        final Stream<TSRecord> stream = database.stream(dsName, parameter);
        closer.add(stream::close);
        return stream;
    }
```

What is the equivalent of a CloseableService in Quarkus/RestEasy?

Comment: Hi, there is no such equivalent I am aware of. But you can certainly request this feature to be added by opening an  issue in the Quarkus GitHub repository

Comment: @geoand Thanks. Just posted on your impressive 1.9k issue tracker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/31213